# Python 共有フォルダのファイル ディレクトリ指定について

Tags: python, python3

S3にファイルをアップロードするコードになります。

ローカルPCのデスクトップやドキュメントからファイルを置くと問題なくS3にUPできますが、
ファイルを共有フォルダに置くと「指定したディレクトリが見つからない」とエラーが出ます。

共有フォルダからUPする際にどのように指定するば良いか。
教えていただけますでしょうか。

お手数ですが、宜しくお願いいたします。

**現状のコード**

```
import boto3

accesskey = "11111111111111"
secretkey = "11111111111111"
region = "ap-northeast-3"

s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=accesskey, aws_secret_access_key= secretkey, region_name=region)

filename = r"¥¥192.111.10.111¥共有フォルダ¥マーケ¥test¥test.csv"
bucket_name = "test"

s3.upload_file(filename,bucket_name,filename)
print("uploaded {0}".format(filename))
```

**エラー内容**

```
No such file or directory
```

Comment: filename=\\192.111.10.111\\共有フォルダ\\マーケ\\test\\test.csv　で指定したら行きました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teratailに投稿された以下の質問と回答が参考になるかもしれません。

[awsのs3にファイルアップロード日本語](https://teratail.com/questions/32532)